# Random iOS 6 crash with iOS 7 SDK

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, uikit, uiappearance, base-sdk

My current main Application is randomly crashing on iOS 6 devices when i compile with iOS 7. It is system deep i think and don't know how to fix this little nasty bug. In my App there are plenty of iOS 6 user with this crash and it's driving me nuts.

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSGenericException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x32b902a3 __exceptionPreprocess + 162
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3a8b897f objc_exception_throw + 30
2  CoreFoundation                 0x32b8fd85 -[NSException name]
3  UIKit                          0x34d22f75 __54+[_UIAppearance _recordersExcludingSource:withWindow:]_block_invoke_0 + 332
4  CoreFoundation                 0x32b8d62f __NSDictionaryEnumerate + 714
5  UIKit                          0x34d22e1d +[_UIAppearance _recordersExcludingSource:withWindow:] + 136
6  UIKit                          0x34e013a5 UIViewServiceCurrentAppearanceSerializedRepresentations + 60
7  UIKit                          0x34d8f7c7 -[_UIRemoteViewControllerConnectionRequest _sendServiceViewControllerRequest] + 206
8  UIKit                          0x34d8f65d __block_global_5 + 264
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x3acd39f7 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 30
10 UIKit                          0x34d8f551 __76-[_UIRemoteViewControllerConnectionRequest _connectToViewControllerOperator]_block_invoke_0 + 92
11 UIKit                          0x34d98bc5 __block_global_0 + 32
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x3acd53f7 dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$mp + 42
13 UIKit                          0x34d98ba1 __73-[_UIViewServiceSessionEndpoint connectToDeputyOfType:connectionHandler:]_block_invoke_0 + 88
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x3acd011f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x3acd3ecf _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 142
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x3acd3dc1 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 40
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x3acd491d _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 184
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x3acd4ac1 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 84
19 libsystem_c.dylib              0x3ad04a11 _pthread_wqthread + 360
20 libsystem_c.dylib              0x3ad048a4 start_wqthread + 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a Exception breakpoint you will get some more info about your crash.. for adding a Exception Breakpoint have a look on this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Answer (score 0):

Add breakpoints step into every line of code to find the bug , Or maybe this would help you read crash reports. http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs